# Extracting first sentence from a paragraph

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Is there a way we can extract first sentence from a paragraph. Can regex be used here. if yes How?

say for example the paragraph below has two sentences, and I need first sentence:

"The Japanese loan will be available at 0.1% interest rate on Oct. 25 and India will be able to repay this in 50 years. Repayment will begin 15 years after the loan is received."

My Desired output: The Japanese loan will be available at 0.1% interest rate on Oct. 25 and India will be able to repay this in 50 years.

how can i do that? Is there a VBA code using regex that can be used here?

Regards
Karan

Comment: How would a regex determine where the sentence ended? You can't use the period (dot), because there's one in *0.1%* and *Oct.*. You clearly can't use a space, and can't use initial case (because of *Japanese*, *Oct.* and *India*). How a regular expression would deal with those issues? You can't use a regular expression to identify things you can't define rules as to how to identify it. How **specifically** do you define the end of the sentence in the paragraph you provided?

Comment: Are there two spaces after the period at the end of the sentence? (only works old school typing style)

Comment: @ForwardEd: Two spaces following a period ended at least four decades ago. Clearly not appropriate unless you're dealing with old, historical text.

Comment: I did state old school.  I still use it.

Comment: I still like using two spaces at the end of each sentence.  I probably still type like that into all my SO answers, despite knowing at the back of my brain that the HTML will just reduce it to one visible space anyway.  :D

Comment: @pnuts: The asker of the question needs to define the rules.

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions can definitely be used. The following uses a simple but typical definition of "end of sentence": a `.`, `!` or `?` followed by either 1) at least one space then a capital letter, or 2) the end of the text.

```
Public Function TheFirstSentence(ByRef Text As String) As String

  With New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    .Pattern = ".*?[.!?](?= +[A-Z]|$)"
    If .test(Text) Then
      TheFirstSentence = .Execute(Text)(0).Value
    Else
      TheFirstSentence = vbNullString
    End If
  End With

End Function
```

Just remember to enable the reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`.